# How to handle click on notification triggered using Script Editor?

Tags: applescript

I am developing a simple script that triggers notifications using `display notification`.

Once the script has been exported as an application using "Script Editor", I noticed that clicking on the notification runs the script again.

I would like to handle this use case differently.

Comment: **AppleScript** does not provide for callbacks from a **display notification** _command_.

Comment: @user3439894 Thanks! But what about some kind of runtime variable I could read to see how the app was executed?